# Using only NAND and NOT gates to represent a logic function that isn't an SOP/POS?

Tags: boolean-algebra, nand

I understand that I should repreatedly use deMorgan's theorem until I am left only with NAND/NOT gates. This is easy when the starting function is an SOP/POS. However when it isn't, I get confused as to what my steps should be (both agebraically and graphically). Consider the function below:

[image]

whose circuit looks like this:
[image]

I think I can do it algebraically but apparently it is possible to do it graphically (which should be the simpler approach). I can't get my head around doing it graphically, as the process is a little more involved than it is with SOP/POS. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Rather than So much problem description, you could share how much you are able to solve. If there is a tweak or hint needed, then definitely people will help. But expecting help without sharing what you have done till now makes many lose interest in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203605/what-is-the-point-of-converting-everything-to-nand-nor-and-how-do-you-do-it-righ/203612#203612

Comment: Why does the function need to be a sum-of-products or product-of-sums for you to use that method?

Answer (score 0):

That expression  has ANDs, ORs(+), and NOTs(').
You already have the NOT.
A NAND followed by NOT is AND.
A NAND preceeded by NOT for each input is OR.

Answer (score 0):

So graphically, replace each gate with it's NAND equivalent.

For an OR gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3taP6m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Remove double NOT gates (if they occur).  NAND2 and NAND3 can be removed in the following schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flDEdC.png)</sup>

Edit...

First part of circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPDRZa.png)</sup>

In this circuit, NAND3 & NAND4 and NAND7 & NAND8 are redundant and can be removed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjV9pP.png)</sup>